# Facebook global activity monitor

Tags: facebook

I'm looking for some way (web-pages, API, whatever) to have some data on global Facebook activity, some information like:

1. How many status updates / likes / comments in the last few minutes all over Facebook
2. How many users are online, from which country or devices
3. Any other kind of activity

I've tried to look on the internet and a lot of APIs (like the Graph API) are user-based—which means that you have to start a query on a specific user—, while I'm looking for some global information, not linked with any specific user or page.

Any idea?

Comment: I expect that Facebook considers that information trade secrets. I doubt that anyone outside of Facebook would ever see that information, and certainly not in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Facebook internally has a log for this, but as an API service this will place tremendous strain on performance. Your best options will be looking out for press releases from Facebook when they do release data for PR purposes.

http://newsroom.fb.com/

Another place that this data will be partially available is through some of their official mobile applications with a call to `graph.facebook.com/app_id/insights`